# Mysql subquery per row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to show a matrix table with the results from a vendor in a category. Like:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------+
|           | Category 1  | Category 2  | ...  |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------+
| Vendor 1  |       8900  |          0  | ...  |
| Vendor 2  |      56890  |       4000  | ...  |
|      ...  |        ...  |        ...  | ...  |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+------+
```

I already made a query for just one vendor:

```
SELECT ut.unit_name, IFNULL(SUM(commission_fix_out),0)
FROM transaction t
JOIN office_per_transaction opt
ON t.id = opt.transaction_id
JOIN_vendor_per_transaction ppt
ON t.id = ppt.transaction_id
AND ppt.vendor_id = 2
RIGHT JOIN unit_type ut
ON t.unit_type_id = ut.id
AND transaction_end_week BETWEEN 0 AND 14
AND YEAR(transaction_end_date) = 2012
GROUP BY ut.id
```

Which gives me following result:

```
+-------------+---------+
| Category    | Result  |
+-------------+---------+
| Category 1  |  56890  |
| Category 2  |   4000  |
|        ...  |    ...  |
+-------------+---------+
```

Now i would like to see a concatenation of this query per vendor in a given office.

First, I tried replacing `AND ppt.vendor_id = 2` with `AND ppt.vendor_id IN (SELECT id FROM vendor WHERE office_id = 1)` but that gave me the total result of all the vendors in that office.

Secondly, I tried using a subquery. But that gave me an error stating **unknown column**.

What i want to achieve is a resultset like:

```
+-----------+--------- -------+
| Vendor    | Results         |
+-----------+-----------------+
| Vendor 1  | 8900,0,...      |
| Vendor 2  | 56890,4000,...  |
| ...       | ...,...,...     |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

Am i trying something unrealistic and should i rather perform above query per vendor. Or am i missing something here?

@SashiKant I've tried many queries last days, but it was something like this:

```
SELECT v.id, GROUP_CONCAT(r.result) FROM vendor v, 
   ( SELECT ut.unit_name, IFNULL(SUM(commission_fix_out),0) as result 
     FROM transaction t JOIN office_per_transaction opt ON t.id = opt.transaction_id 
     JOIN vendor_per_transaction ppt ON t.id = ppt.transaction_id 
     AND ppt.vendor_id = p.id 
     RIGHT JOIN unit_type ut ON unit_type_id = ut.id 
     AND transaction_end_week BETWEEN 0 AND 14 
     AND YEAR(transaction_end_date) = 2012 GROUP BY ut.id) as r
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to join against the vendors table to get the vendors you want (rather than a single vendor). Also you need more clauses in the GROUP BY (and you really should use all the non aggregate columns from the SELECT in the GROUP BY clause - mysql doesn't object but most flavours of SQL do object if you miss some out).

Something like this (not tested so please excuse any typos)

```
SELECT vendor_id, ut.id, ut.unit_name, IFNULL(SUM(commission_fix_out),0)
FROM transaction t
INNER JOIN office_per_transaction opt
ON t.id = opt.transaction_id
INNER JOIN_vendor_per_transaction ppt
ON t.id = ppt.transaction_id
INNER JOIN vendor ve
ON ve.id = ppt.vendor_id 
RIGHT JOIN unit_type ut
ON t.unit_type_id = ut.id
AND transaction_end_week BETWEEN 0 AND 14
AND YEAR(transaction_end_date) = 2012
WHERE ve.office_id = 1
GROUP BY vendor_id, ut.id, ut.unit_name
ORDER BY vendor_id, ut.id, ut.unit_name
```

If you want a row per vendor with a single column for all the amounts for that vendor then something like this.

```
SELECT vendor_id, GROUP_CONCAT(CommisionAmount)
FROM (
SELECT vendor_id, ut.id, ut.unit_name, IFNULL(SUM(commission_fix_out),0) AS CommisionAmount
FROM transaction t
INNER JOIN office_per_transaction opt
ON t.id = opt.transaction_id
INNER JOIN_vendor_per_transaction ppt
ON t.id = ppt.transaction_id
INNER JOIN vendor ve
ON ve.id = ppt.vendor_id 
RIGHT JOIN unit_type ut
ON t.unit_type_id = ut.id
AND transaction_end_week BETWEEN 0 AND 14
AND YEAR(transaction_end_date) = 2012
WHERE ve.office_id = 1
GROUP BY vendor_id, ut.id, ut.unit_name
ORDER BY vendor_id, ut.id, ut.unit_name) Sub1
```

Comment: This doesn't help as it doesn't give the result of each category for a vendor. But, thanks anyway.

Comment: It should, but as one row per category per vendor. That can easily be sorted into a row per vendor and a column per category in the langauge you are using. To bring it back concatenated I have done an extra bit above

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Pseudo SQL:

```
select vendor, group_concat(result)
from mytable
group by vendor
```

You might "simplify" it by creating a view. Since I don't know your table structure, this is just guessing

```
create view commissions as
    SELECT ppt.vendor_id as vendor, ut.unit_name as category,
           IFNULL(SUM(commission_fix_out),0) as commission
    FROM transaction t
    JOIN office_per_transaction opt
    ON t.id = opt.transaction_id
    JOIN_vendor_per_transaction ppt
    ON t.id = ppt.transaction_id
    RIGHT JOIN unit_type ut
    ON t.unit_type_id = ut.id
    AND transaction_end_week BETWEEN 0 AND 14
    AND YEAR(transaction_end_date) = 2012
    GROUP BY ppt.vendor_id, ut.id;
```

and then select

```
select vendor, group_concat(commission)
from commissions
group by vendor;
```

Comment: That view only fetches the result from vendor 2, is there a way that vendor id is variable?

Comment: @J.Ghyllebert Oops, I just copied blindly your select. I removed now `and ppt.vendor_id = 2`, but there are still restrictions with `transaction_end_week` and `transaction_end_date`. Just adapt the view as needed.